# Cordova/Phonegap ios CORS perpetually loading

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using xcode with an angular/ionic framework hybrid app for cordova. On my windows machine, I've been able to build and run for blackberry and android with this code successfully so I'm not sure what's not right. The back end is a Microsoft Web API restful service with basic windows authentication from active directory sending back JSON serialized data.

The main data call boils down to:

```
      $http.get('http://192.168.0.12/api/values/1').
                   success(onSuccuess).
                   error(onFailure);
```

I'm sure I have the usual  in the config and NSAllowsArbitraryLoads on the info.plist. I also have the most permissible "Content-Security_policy" meta tag on the main index.html file.

I'm fairly sure none of these are the issue because the loads will immediately fail in the safari development simulator dialog. My issue is that the load simply never finishes. If I double click the resource name in the "Network" tab, safari will open and load the data appropriately.

Again, this fails in the osx simulator and on a device hooked to the network. But works fine on my physical blackberry (Z10 lol) and android simulator on my windows machine.

Comment: If I turn on anonymous authentication on the webapi server, the connections go through. So the windows authentication login prompt isn't coming up.

Comment: If anyone wants to know. I think this fixed the issue. I'm kind of in disbelief. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-auth-dialog